# Here Map shows same map for traffic and terrain map scheme

Tags: android, here-api

I am working on here map and having problem with traffic and terrain scheme. It always shows the traffic even in terrain.

My code is 
map.setMapScheme(Map.Scheme.TERRAIN_DAY);
map.setMapScheme(Map.Scheme.NORMAL_TRAFFIC_DAY);

both result is same. does any one face the same issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `Map.Scheme` you use is actually independent of the `Map` traffic setting. The `NORMAL_TRAFFIC_DAY` scheme is simply optimized for displaying traffic on the `Map`.

To control traffic on the `Map` use the `Map#isTrafficInfoVisible` and `Map#setTrafficInfoVisible(boolean visible)` APIs.

Comment: Do i have to manually hide/show traffic? terrain view should not show the traffic. on here map website it showing terrain view but why not through api?

Comment: Yes, `Map` schemes are independent of the traffic visibility setting, so if you previously had traffic enabled, as your changing to `TERRAIN_DAY ` you would have to call `setTrafficInfoVisible(false)` as well to stop showing the traffic.